# Capturing events from multiple threads in a time window

Tags: multithreading

I am working on a multithreaded application where multiple threads are deployed to capture events from sensors attached to each thread. Example a distance sensor employed to capture proximity (distance) of objects. The output of these threads could either be a binary 1 or 0 (similar to ON or OFF). Binary 1, when the distance is < 2m, and Binary 0 if it is greater than 2m. So basically just 1 or 0 as an output. There also exists a main thread which captures data from all these multiple threads **for a specific amount of time span (kind of a fixed interval moving window)** and does some logic to make decisions from the data captured in that time window. Those multiple threads connected to sensors should continuously log the two states (1 or 0) to the main thread. I am a bit indecisive in designing the data structure and logic that would contain the outputs of these threads. So, the requirement is when I read the main thread window, I should be able to estimate (in fact retrieve to some reasonable precision like a second) that the data from this sensor (from a sensor thread) was 1 or 0 for this much time and at that particular time and so on.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the sensor raise an interrupt when their state change, or do they need to be polled?

Comment: How many cores do you have? If you create more threads than cores and if you are continuously logging the state of each sensor then you are likely to kill performance. You really should have a limited number of threads doing the polling of multiple sensors each to get the greatest throughput.

Comment: @LieRyan, they are polled.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have 8 cores (using my i7 PC as of now) and to be honest, as of now I will be having only 4 sensor threads. (Distance sensor was just an example, I will be using some camera sensors with image processing algorithms in real, and thus kept them into multiple threads. Also, they are programmed to detect different objects at the same time, so different image processing algorithm in each thread).

Comment: @AKay - It would be good if you could do two things: (1) post your code, and (2) actually ask a question. Right now your just making a rather abstract statement.

Comment: @Enigmativity - You are right, but I apologize I haven't started any coding yet. This that you see here is actually kind of a pre-thinking where I am a bit confused what kind of a data-structure I should lay the algorithm in.

Comment: @AKay - Then you should provide the API you're working with. It's a bit hard to design/code against a abstract description.